# How do I limit the number of rows returned in a Netezza query?

Tags: sql, netezza

I want to run a basic query, but return only the first ten rows of the table from Netezza

```
select a.*
  from some_schema.some_table a
 where rownum < 10
```

What is the Netezza way of looking at just those few rows?

Comment: It's not really the "First ten rows of the table", it's just SOME 10 rows from the table. First implies order. Without Order By tables have no order.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ah!  Just found it.

For Netezza this query is

```
select a.*
  from some_schema.some_table a
 limit 10
```

-mcpeterson

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT * FROM schema_name..table_name LIMIT 100 OFFSET 50
```

**LIMIT** is number of records you need, and **OFFSET** is from where to count!

Answer (score 2):

The below query should work for any random 'N' rows in a netezza table.

```
SELECT COLNAME1 FROM ( SELECT COLNAME1 FROM SCHEMANAME..TABLENAME ORDER BY COLNAME1 LIMIT n) A
MINUS
SELECT COLNAME1 FROM ( SELECT COLNAME1 FROM SCHEMANAME..TABLENAME ORDER BY COLNAME1 LIMIT m) B
```

Note : n>m ( m,n are integers )